# Check php script for results with jquery each x time

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, real-time

I have this php script:

```
<?php
    echo "Welcome!<br>";
    sleep(3);
    echo "Something else<br>";
    sleep(3);
    echo "Something else 2<br>";
?>
```

How can I do with jQuery to display results on real time or almost real time without waiting the whole script to finish, for example checking every seconds for new results until the script stop loading?

What if I have a php loop like this one:

```
<?php
    while($x<10) {
        echo "Hi<br>";
        $x++;
    }
?>
```

Can I do the same on this case?

This is my actual jQuery, but it wait until php script is complete:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#submit').click(function() {
            event.preventDefault(); 
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'index.php',           
                data: { url : $('#url').val() },
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#div").append(data);
                }          
            });     
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make 3 different PHP scripts and write an AJAX call for each one

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you should check out this comment at the php docs:
http://php.net/manual/de/function.flush.php#76039

This will send content to the browser before finishing the script.